# Pass an argument from view to partial view action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have partial view like this defined in `Products` controller:

```
 public PartialViewResult _Comments(int productId)
    {
        var comments = _CommentsRepo.GetCommentsByProductId(productId);
        return PartialView(comments);

    }
```

Partial view is in Shared folder:
In  `Products` view I wrote something like:

```
  @{Html.RenderPartial("_Comments", new { productId = Model.Id });}
```

but it seems I can't find best overload for me.
It seems I can also use @Html.Action helper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RenderPartial` renders a partial view directly - it *doesn't* call an action. You need to use `RenderAction`:

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("_Comments", new { productId = Model.Id }); }
```

Or just `Action`:

```
@Html.Action("_Comments", new { productId = Model.Id });
```